# A question regarding smooth curves

Tags: complex-analysis

According to Definition $4.2$ of Complex Analysis by Bak and Newman, a curve is *smooth* if it is piecewise differentiable AND $\dot{z}(t)\neq0$, except at a finite number of points.

Can someone give me an example of a piecewise differentiable curve which is NOT smooth under this context?

I'm confused as to why we would necessitate that $\dot{z}(t)\neq0$ **except** at a finite number of points, doesn't that negate the premise?

I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: $\gamma(t) =t^2\sin(1/t)$ if $t\neq 0$ and 0 otherwise is a differentiable (real) curve, but the derivative vanishes infinitely many times in the interval $[-1/\pi,1/\pi]$ for instance.

Comment: @peek-a-boo can you give an example in the complex plane where $\dot{z}(t)=0$ infinitely many times?

Comment: @peek-a-boo $z(t)=t^2\sin(1/t)+it^2\sin(1/t)$ if $t\neq0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Actually, peek-a-boo's original curve *is in the complex plane*. Your variant merely makes it run along the diagonal line through $0$ and $1+i$ instead of the horizontal line through $0$ and $1$. An alternate example would be a curve that stops at one point for a while before moving on. For example $$z(t) = \begin{cases}e^{6\pi i t},&t\in[0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1]\\1,&t\in(1/3, 2/3)\end{cases}$$ While for some uses of smooth curves, this would be fine, for others it introduces technical problems that would require special handling. Easiest just to disallow it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that's true... for some (strange) reason I didn't interpret it as being in the complex plane (even though $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$) and instead pictured the function (for $t\neq0$) in the complex plane being represented by $z(t)=t+it^2\sin(1/t)$. Thanks for providing the additional example (and clarity, i.e., dispelling foolish thinking on my behalf). I understand things a lot better now.